# Error while finding all the classes that are loaded in an spring boot application

Tags: linux, spring-boot, shell, unix

I am trying to find all the classes that are loaded when my spring boot application is started.
After finding all the classes that are loaded I am doing a sort on them to find the class which is invoked the most using the below command.

```
java -cp myjar.jar -verbose:class Myclass | grep Loaded | clever sed | sort *
```

But this command is giving me the below error:-

```
**sort: Is a directory**
```

Does anyone know what am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK you don't need to use `*` after sort command as you are already piping output of other commands to sort.

Comment: and what is `clever sed` ?

Comment: Can you please share the output of `java -cp myjar.jar -verbose:class Myclass | grep Loaded `  Also what is `clever` ?